# the "java.lang.NullPointerException" error because of com.amazon.redshift.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3

*im devoloping a andoid application about accounting*
*with  amazon s3 service(mysql)*
*and*
**im getting same errors since one week its wasting time;**
*can anyone could grab my hands in this trouble *
i chacked my driver for 2-3 times . drivers's absolutly on new version

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.meicode.ekrandenemefln, PID: 7684
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.meicode.ekrandenemefln/org.meicode.ekrandenemefln.secondlayer}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.security.CodeSource java.security.ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method java.security.CodeSource java.security.ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource() on a null object reference 
        at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.getJdbcIniFile(Driver.java:877)
        at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.connect(Driver.java:258)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
        at org.meicode.ekrandenemefln.awsHelper.getConnection(awsHelper.java:13)
        at org.meicode.ekrandenemefln.secondlayer.onCreate(secondlayer.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**and this is my code here :**

*i want to do here get informations from user and
send this datas to server*

```
package org.meicode.ekrandenemefln;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.sql.;

public class secondlayer extends FragmentActivity {//AppCompatActivity

    private Button onayButton;
    private EditText musteriInput;
    private EditText urunInput;
    private EditText adetIn;
    private EditText fiyatIn;
    private EditText maliyetIn;
    private ImageView goback;


    private int adetInput,maliyetInput,fiyatInput;
    long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();

    java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);


    private Connection connection = null;
    //dbHelper helper = new dbHelper();
    //onay onay = new onay();
    //ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
    //eklemeDb ekleme = new eklemeDb();
    awsHelper awshelper = new awsHelper();


    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet;



    @Override
    protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondlayer);
        //burdan sonra ...

        try {
            connection = awshelper.getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println(e);
        }


        musteriInput = findViewById(R.id.musteriInput);

        urunInput = findViewById(R.id.urunInput);

        adetIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adetInput);
        adetInput = Integer.parseInt(adetIn.getText().toString());

        fiyatIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fiyatInput);
        fiyatInput = Integer.parseInt(fiyatIn.getText().toString());

        maliyetIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maliyetInput);
        maliyetInput = Integer.parseInt(maliyetIn.getText().toString());

        goback = findViewById(R.id.goback);


        //özel durum
        veriler veri = new veriler(musteriInput.toString(),urunInput.toString(),adetInput,fiyatInput,maliyetInput,date);


        veri.setMusteriInput(musteriInput.toString());

        veri.setAdetInput(adetInput);

        veri.setUrunInput(urunInput.toString());

        veri.setFiyatInput(fiyatInput);

        veri.setMaliyetInput(maliyetInput);

        veri.setTarih(date);
```

Comment: Could you provide your version of driver which you're using, please? I suppose this is bug-related  problem and you need to test other versions of it.

Comment: It sounds as though `Class.getProtectionDomain()` is returning null.

Comment: also what version of Android you're using 4 or 5? do you reproduce this error on both?